# Inline binding of external function to class method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class, ecmascript-next

Let's say I have a function that returns a function like this:

```
function createGreeter(logger) {
  return function greet(greeting) {
    logger.log(greeting + ', ' + this.name);
  }
}
```

And a class

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) {this.name = name;}
}
```

If I want to assign a greet method to the `Person` class that uses the console as the logger, I can think of several ways:

```
1.

class Person {
  constructor(name) {this.name = name;}

  greet(greeting) {
    return createGreeter(console).call(this, greeting);
  }
}

2.

class Person {
  constructor(name) {this.name = name;}
}

Person.prototype.greet = createGreeter(console);
```

However, I think both of these are somewhat ugly; 1) creates an, essentially, unnecessary wrapper method that simply binds `this` and calls the function, and 2) modifies the prototype outside of the class body which in my opinion makes the class API less clear.

Is there no clearer/shorter syntax for inline assignment and binding of an external function to a class method. I'm thinking something like:

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) {this.name = name;}

  greet: createGreeter(console)
}
```

...which resembles how you would be able to assign a function in an object literal. But this doesn't work, obviously. Is there something similar (now, or upcoming)?

Also, I'm wondering about the memory consumption and/or performance aspects of returning a closure as in 1) if the returned function is large. Every time the greet method is called on a `Person` object, a new function object will be created even though we always want to pass the same parameters (`console`) to it. So yet another approach could be to declare `const consoleGreeter = createGreeter(console)` before the class definition and implement greet as `return consoleGreeter.call(this, greeting)`, but would it be worth it?

Comment: Can you create a snippet to replicate the issue? It works `Person.prototype.greet = createGreeter(console);
var p1 = new Person( "abc" );
p1.greet( "10" );`

Comment: ?? I know it works. I was asking for a clearer or shorter way of accomplishing the same result. JS has a loooot of convenient shorthands, I was hoping I had missed one for this case.

Comment: You mentioned that *But this doesn't work, obviously* for `Person.prototype.greet = createGreeter(console);`. Can you replicate this?

Comment: The second approach of yours looks good to me. What kind of pitfalls that you found with that one?

Comment: @gurvinder372 The prototype approach is not the one he is talking about. It is working and it should. But he simply gave a sample code which is just for illustration and that one wont work, he said.

Comment: Exactly, thanks Rajaprabhu. My made up code "greet: createGreeter(console)" is what doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) {this.name = name;}
}

Person.prototype.greet = createGreeter(console);
```

is the proper way to do this, unless there are other concerns (it will have problems in TypeScript).

This can be also done with [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), which are stage 3 proposal and will likely land in ES2018:

```
class Person {
  greet = createGreeter(console);
}
```

Which is a shortcut for

```
class Person {
  constructor() {
    this.greet = createGreeter(console);
  }
}
```

First snippet evaluates `createGreeter(console)` once and assigns the method to class prototype. Second snippet evaluates it every time the class is instantiated and assigns the method to class instance, which is less effective.

Comment: That is very interesting, it's actually pretty similar to my "made-up" code, but it's interesting to learn that the code will be evaluated upon construction as opposed to at declaration. I could of course store a `const consoleGreeter = createGreeter(console);` here as well to avoid the cost of creating the new function object every time, but I am definitely leaning towards the direct prototype manipulation to avoid having to do that.

Comment: See also this related answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46729995/3731501 . The case is really close to yours but is specific to TS to some degree, and OP deliberately tried to avoid direct `prototype` access.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here is an alternative to `bind` external method to `class`

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) {this.name = name;}
  get greet() { return createGreeter(console) }
}
```

Just checked, `this` is also working fine.

Comment: Thanks, you and Patrick apparently answered essentially the same thing at the same time. Clever solution indeed.

Answer (score 1):

This would achieve the same effect #1, since the wrapper is invoked each time the method is accessed. If that's okay with you to improve readability...

```js
function createGreeter(logger) {
  return function greet(greeting) {
    logger.log(`${greeting}, ${this.name}`);
  };
}

class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  get greet() {
    return createGreeter(console);
  }
}

let person = new Person('Patrick');

person.greet('Hello');
```

Comment: I have to admit this use of `get` caught me confused for a while; to have a property return a function is pretty clever indeed! And that it was automatically bound to `this` was also good to know.

Comment: Also appreciate the full, runnable code snippet, thanks!